# Pyspark - How can I convert parquet file to text file with delimiter

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet, apache-spark-sql, csv

I have a parquet file with the following schema:

|DATE|ID|

I would like to convert it into a text file with tab delimiters as follows:

20170403    15284503

How can I do this in pyspark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Spark 2.0+

```
spark.read.parquet(input_path)
```

to read the parquet file into a dataframe. [DataFrameReader](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader)

```
spark.write.csv(output_path, sep='\t')
```

to write the dataframe out as tab delimited. [DataFrameWriter](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter)

Answer (score 1):

You can read your *.parquet* file in **python** using `DataFrame` and with the use of `list` data structure, save that in a text file. the sample code is here:
this code, reads word2vec (word to vector) that is output of *spark mllib WordEmbeddings class* in a *.parquet* file and convert it to tab delimiter *.txt* file.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import csv

data = pq.read_pandas('C://...//parquetFile.parquet', columns=['word', 'vector']).to_pandas()
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

vector = df['vector'].tolist()

word = df['word']
word = word.tolist()

k = [[]]
for i in range(0, word.__len__()):
    l = []
    l.append(word[i])
    l.extend(vector[i])
    k.append(l)

#you can not save data frame directly to .txt file.
#so, write df to .csv file at first
with open('C://...//csvFile.csv', "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in k:
        writer.writerow(row)


outputTextFile = 'C://...//textFile.txt'

with open(outputTextFile, 'w') as f:
    for record in k:
        if (len(record) > 0):
            for element in record:
                #tab delimiter elements
                f.write("%s\t" % element)
            f.write("%s" % element)
            #add enter after each records
            f.write("\n")
```

I hope it helps :)